# Is this a user/pass connection or an email communication connection?

Tags: centos, email, logging, email-server, log-files

I have lines like these in `/var/log/messages`:

`Jul 12 01:26:00 h2 xinetd[1596]: START: smtp pid=11253 from=::ffff:221.219.213.54`

I need to know if that is an email connection like the ones being made when one server sends email to another. OR it is a connection where user logs in to server (usually with user/password) e.g by IMAP or POP and freely sends emails.

Edit: that IP shows up in the header of a bounced email

```
Received: from unknown (HELO 176.9.76.194) (221.219.213.54)
  by h2.adriantnt.com with SMTP; 12 Jul 2015 01:26:02 +0200
Received: from 233.246.168.139 by 221.219.213.54; Sat, 11 Jul 2015 22:16:46 -0100
```

`176.9.76.194` is my server

I am not sure if it is a forged bounce or a message sent from my server, the later meaning that a someone has unauthorized access to the server, as it is not normally open to IMAP/POP type user logins.

Comment: Could you please provide more context from the mailserver logs?

Answer (score 0):

This line only tell us that you are getting a connection to xinited server "awaking" the smtp server by a connection requested form the given ip.

Take a look on the smtp server log on what is the operation the daemon is being requested. The provided information won't give us any clue regarding what you ask, and is likely to be voted down if you don't add more data.

If by user logs in to server you mean SSH, it happens in SSHD port that is 22 as default, while smtp port is default 25 when any kind of encryption is requested.

Comment: I added more info, does it mean anything ?

Comment: Reading the information you added, take a look on the smtp (don't know which one you are using) daemon log. At a glance, it is only someone who telneted your port (maybe trying to see if it is an open relay if you want to look in a security paranoid way)
Check your daemon log to see if an operation was performed there or it was just a connection opened and a HELO comand issued

Answer (score 0):

That log only shows that xinetd received a request on the port that is associated to smtp and sent it to the smtp process.

Since you're on centos, if you want to see user login activity you'll have to look at the `/var/log/wtmp` file using the `utmpdump` command.

Comment: I added some more info, I meant it might be a user login to an email protocol like imap or pop. The `/var/log/wtmp` doesn't seem to cover that, or does it ? I think is only ftp.